# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near at line 1",

Tags: python, mysql, visual-studio-code, syntax-error, postman

I tried to post on postman using vscode and mysql

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'release, genre, console, price, summary, video_link, image_link, image2_link, de' at line 1

**What I used in vscode**

```
INSERT INTO games (Category_id, title, release, genre, console, price, 
                        summary, video_link, image_link, image2_link, developer, category) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

**What I used in postman**

```
{
    "Category_id": "3",
    "title": "Monster Hunter World",
    "release": "2018",
    "genre": "Actiom",
    "console": "PS4",
    "price": 69,
    "summary": "hunting",
    "video_link": "youtube.com",
    "image_link": "image1",
    "image2_link": "image2",
    "developer": "Capcom",
    "category": "new"
}
```

Comment: The `near release` indicates a syntax problem immediately _before_ the column name `release`. Are you certain that is _exactly_ what was in your code? Was there a comma missing after an earlier column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`release` is a [reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html). If you intend to you it as a column name, you need to escape it:

```sql
INSERT INTO games (Category_id, 
                   title, 
                   `release`, -- Here, using the `s 
                   genre, 
                   console,
                   price, 
                   summary, 
                   video_link, 
                   image_link, 
                   image2_link, 
                   developer, 
                   category) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```